Craft5: Failure to create a passkey
I'm trying craft5 ,I'm seeing an error with passkey registration.
When I try to save my passkey using FaceID on my iPhone,
"Unable to load the data" pops up in cp.
The passkey seemed to be saved on the device (iPhone) side.
I checked the debug tool bar and found an exception in the CredentialLoader of the WebAuthn module.
here's logs , how solve it?
Webauthn\Exception\InvalidDataException: Unable to create the response object in /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/Exception/InvalidDataException.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/PublicKeyCredentialLoader.php(188): Webauthn\Exception\InvalidDataException::create()
#1 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/PublicKeyCredentialLoader.php(92): Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialLoader->createResponse()
#2 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/PublicKeyCredentialLoader.php(119): Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialLoader->loadArray()
#3 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Auth.php(449): Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialLoader->load()
#4 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/AuthController.php(221): craft\services\Auth->verifyPasskeyCreationResponse()
#5 [internal function]: craft\controllers\AuthController->actionVerifyPasskeyCreation()
#6 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#7 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#8 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#9 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(349): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#10 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(650): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#11 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(311): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest()
#12 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#13 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#14 {main}

Next Webauthn\Exception\InvalidDataException: Unable to load the data in /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/Exception/InvalidDataException.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/web-auth/webauthn-lib/src/PublicKeyCredentialLoader.php(124): Webauthn\Exception\InvalidDataException::create()
#1 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Auth.php(449): Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialLoader->load()
#2 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/AuthController.php(221): craft\services\Auth->verifyPasskeyCreationResponse()
#3 [internal function]: craft\controllers\AuthController->actionVerifyPasskeyCreation()
#4 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#5 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#6 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#7 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(349): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#8 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(650): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#9 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(311): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest()
#10 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#11 /home/craft-study/develop/craftcms/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#12 {main}


Sounds a lot like this bug, which was fixed in Craft 5.0.1.

Timely notice , Thank you!!
